# Updated Firebase Crashlytics on iOS, getting a bunch of analyzer issues

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

Using CocoaPods, I just updated my Firebase Crashlytics with iOS11 as the deployment target. It said it installed Firebase 8.0.0 (was 3.6.0) and Google Utilities 7.4.1 (was 1.3.2).

When I ran the analyzer in Xcode, I got a bunch of urgent warnings:

> nanopb/pb_decode.c:541:24: Dereference of null pointer
>
> nanopb/pb_decode.c:547:9: Null pointer passed as 1st argument to
> memory set function
>
> GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:300:9:
> nil passed to a callee that requires a non-null 1st parameter
>
> GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:570:37:
> nil passed to a callee that requires a non-null 1st parameter

And also got a few coding conventions warnings:

> GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:484:15:
> Potential null dereference.  According to coding standards in
> 'Creating and Returning NSError Objects' the parameter may be null
>
> GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:513:15:
> Potential null dereference.  According to coding standards in
> 'Creating and Returning NSError Objects' the parameter may be null
>
> GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORFlatFileStorage.m:537:15:
> Potential null dereference.  According to coding standards in
> 'Creating and Returning NSError Objects' the parameter may be null

I haven't run the analyzer for a while so not sure how long this has been there, but is this a cause for concern? Has anyone else experienced this? Is it matter of them just needing to update their code for the latest Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like new analyzer errors introduced by Xcode 12.5. They haven't been caught by Firebase CI since GitHub Actions is still [using 12.4 by default](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/runs/2635703752?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:14).

I created https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8134 and https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/issues/667 to track.